# Need help with Infopath Number type

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I need to add "Version" to my form but the Number type is giving me trouble.  I need to RESTRICT entry to AT LEAST 3 characters (as in 2.0) but no more than 5 characters (99.99).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Text Box Properties - > Data Validation -> Add
2. Choose ‘does not match pattern’ condition
3. Choose custom pattern and enter this pattern \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
   [image]
4. Enter ScreenTip and Message
   [image]

Comment: I like that approach better than mine. Note to self: Learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a validation rule on the "Version" field with these three conditions, combined with OR, using expressions

not(string-length(substring-before(., ".")) < 3)
not(string-length(substring-after(., ".")) < 3)
string-length(.) < 3

[image]

You MUST enter a screen tip for the field, otherwise InfoPath 2010 will DELETE your validation rules.
[image]